# i/o timeout when binding to a local IP address

Tags: go, networking, ipv6

So I'm binding a local IP address to use in a http request.
This is the code I'm using:

```
    localAddr, err := net.ResolveIPAddr("ip6", laddr)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    localTCPAddr := net.TCPAddr{
        IP: localAddr.IP,
    }

    client := &http.Client{
        Transport: &http.Transport{
            Proxy: http.ProxyFromEnvironment,
            DialContext: (&net.Dialer{
                LocalAddr: &localTCPAddr,
                Timeout:   30 * time.Second,
                KeepAlive: 30 * time.Second,
                DualStack: true,
            }).DialContext,
            MaxIdleConns:          100,
            IdleConnTimeout:       90 * time.Second,
            TLSHandshakeTimeout:   10 * time.Second,
            ExpectContinueTimeout: 1 * time.Second,
        },
    }
```

This will panic with a i/o timeout. I'm not sure why this is happening as this code was working yesterday. The only reason I can think of is that I added several thousand IP addresses to a network interface, could this be causing the timeout, and does anyone know any solutions?

EDIT:
Error message:

```
Get https://myip.addr.space: dial tcp [myip]:0->[2607:5300:203:118:1:0:3:8b50]:443: i/o timeout
```

Comment: What is the exact error message that you get? and what is laddr?

Comment: @W.K.S I added the error message to the post. laddr is a valid ipv6 IP.

Comment: Are you trying to source from a link-local address?

Comment: @RonMaupin The IP is part of a subnet that was routed to my vps. I'm experiencing this error after adding 1000s of ips to a network interface so I could bind to them.